# Uso correcto del Service Container de Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una clase la cual se encarga de hacer una petición a una API REST la cual necesita el nombre del jugador y la plataforma en la que juega (simplificare el codigo para ir al grano).

```
class GetPlayerAPI
{

    public function __construct(String $playerName, String $platform)
    {   
     // Aqui construyo la url a la que hacer la peticion
    }

    public function getJsonFromApi()
    {
       // Aqui obtengo los datos mediante CURL
    }
}
```

En el contexto en el que estoy recibo **$playerName** y **$platform** de un formulario por lo que he registrado la clase GetPlayerAPI como servicio de la siguiente manera (usando request)

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('GetPlayerAPI', function () {
            return new GetPlayerAPI(request('playerName'), request('platform'));
        });
    }
```

Y en el controlador:

```
 // Metodo llamado de un formulario
    public function show()
        {
            $playerAPI = resolve('GetPlayerAPI');  
        }
```

Y es aquí donde me saltan las dudas porque si yo quisiera reutilizar la clase GetPlayerAPI en otro contexto en el que no reciba los parámetros mediante un formulario , no podría hacerlo ya que el bind usa los request.

Por ejemplo otro metodo del controlador que no sea llamado desde un formulario:

```
        // Controlador
        public function noLlamadoDeFormulario()
            {
                $playerName = 'Juan';
                $platForm = 'Play Station';

                // No puedo usar la clase GetPlayerAPI
                $playerAPI = resolve('GetPlayerAPI');  
            }
```

Sin duda debo estar haciendo un mal uso del Service Container porque en este caso no es nada practico.

Creo entender que la ventaja del Service Container es la de poder usar las clases en todo el código despreocupandose de su instanciación.

¿Podrían orientarme?

Comment: Para tu ejemplo, no tiene mucho sentido usar el Service Container, que se usa para la inyección de dependencias, básicamente. Tiene utilidad cuando tus clases usan otras clases que implementan interfaces, de modo que el framework pueda inicializarlas automáticamente, o inyectarlas, según la necesidad que tengas ya que pueden ser distintos usos si estás en test o producción, o es una petición de api o de web, etc.

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces en este caso en el que la clase no tiene ninguna dependencia de otra ni voy hacer uso de ninguna interfaz ¿Simplemente la usaría dentro de los metodos de los contraladores del modo $playerAPI = new ($playerName,$platform) ?

Comment: sí: `$playerAPI = new GetPlayerAPI($playerName,$platform);`